# Excel userform vba

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform with several textbox (`Arow1`, `Arow2`,........). When the form opens, the text box are populated from values in a worksheet:
code is

```
Private Sub Arow3_Change()

On Error Resume Next
Me.Arow2.RowSource = ""
Me.Arow4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.Arow2, Sheet5.Range("Data"), 2, 0)
Me.Arow6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.Arow2, Sheet5.Range("Data"), 4, 0)
Me.Arow5 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.Arow2, Sheet5.Range("Data"), 6, 0)
If Me.Arow3.Value > "" Then Me.Arow7 = Me.Arow3.Value * Me.Arow6.Value
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

*Reference*

- `"Data"` refers to a name range, Data Range `2` refers to `"Code no."`
- Data Range `4` refers to `"Sale Price"`
- Data Range `6` refers to `"Stock"`
- `Arow3` is named `"Quantity"`
- `Arow4` is named `"Code No`
- `Arow5` is named `"Stock"`
- `Arow6` is named `"Sale Price"`
- `Arow7` is named `"Total"`

What I need to do is on `Arow6` I need to put the value manually on the user form which will be calculated on `Arow7` `(Quantity * Sale Price = Total)`

How can i do that on the same above give code ?

Comment: can you explain what is the problem ? are you getting an error ? what is not performing as you would want to ?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` - `On Error Go`To 0 block and see what's really going on to handle actual errors

use `val()` function to cast the String textbox values to *real* numbers

so you may want to try this:

```
Private Sub Arow3_Change()
    With Me
        If Not IsNumeric(.Arow3) Then Exit Sub
        .Arow2.RowSource = ""
        .Arow4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Arow2, Sheet5.Range("Data"), 2, 0)
        .Arow6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Arow2, Sheet5.Range("Data"), 4, 0)
        .Arow5 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Arow2, Sheet5.Range("Data"), 6, 0)
        If val(.Arow3.Value) > 0 Then .Arow7 = val(.Arow3.Value) * val(.Arow6.Value)
    End With
End Sub
```

While if you wanted to manage possible LookUp errors (should `Arow2` textbox entered value not `Application.VLookup` function and check its returned `Variant` value against being an `Error`

```
Private Sub Arow3_Change()
    Set Sheet5 = Worksheets("Sheet05")
    With Me
        If Not IsNumeric(.Arow3) Then Exit Sub
        .Arow2.RowSource = ""
        .Arow4 = GetLookUp(.Arow2, 2)
        .Arow6 = GetLookUp(.Arow2, 4)
        .Arow5 = GetLookUp(.Arow2, 6)
        If val(.Arow3.Value) > 0 Then .Arow7 = val(.Arow3.Value) * val(.Arow6.Value)
    End With
End Sub

Function GetLookUp(lookUpValue As Variant, iPos As Long) As Variant
    GetLookUp = Application.VLookup(lookUpValue, Sheet5.Range("Data"), iPos, 0)
    If IsError(GetLookUp) Then GetLookUp = ""
End Function
```